# JS failing to load on some pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have been trying to fix a weird issue and I have no idea where to go now, tried everything

I have this code in header

```
<script>
  var lk = 'http://myredirect.com';
  var pd = 'http://myiframecontent.com';
  $(function() {
    $('#conversion').click(function() {
      if (!$('#iframe').length) {
        $('#pixelframe').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="' + pd + '" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = lk;
        }, 5000);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

and this on my `<body>`

```
<body>
  <a href="#" id="conversion">Our Show code Button</a>
  <div id="pixelframe"></div>
</body>
```

For whatever reason it runs on some landers and on others it wont load.

I have tried playing with the `var lk` and `var pd` destinations, i've set my `setTimeout` to really long delay to let the iframe load, but nothing works.

I tried playing around with the UTF-8 code, but also nothing - i have it set on all landers to  `<meta charset="utf-8">` and have saved the files with or without the encoding.

On all landers the code in header is first thing after loading

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE** - Im pretty sure that for some reason the JS is not fired because the code makes and iframe with the size of 500x500(px) but this iframe wont even show up in the divider.

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in your browser console on the pages where it doesn't work?

Comment: When you say "and on others it wont load" what exactly do you see? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: It doesn't give any errors, it just sits there - the iframe won't open and literally nothing happens. Beside one image file missing i have no errors in Google Chrome console.

I have a date script, where it prints current date on the page, this works fine and this script is few lines below the problematic code.

Comment: I removed ALL Javascripts from the webpage, where this code is not working, just to make sure that something isn't interfering with it, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that I used several conversion buttons on the page with same id! Needed to change the code from #conversion to .conversion

```
<script>
  var lk = 'http://myredirect.com';
  var pd = 'http://myiframecontent.com';
  $(function() {
    $('.conversion').click(function() {
      if (!$('#iframe').length) {
        $('#pixelframe').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="' + pd + '" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = lk;
        }, 5000);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

and for links i now use class="conversion"

Answer (score 0):

hay, the anchor link is may be your problem try out hear `event.preventDefault();`

```
<script>
  var lk = 'http://myredirect.com';
  var pd = 'http://myiframecontent.com';
  $(function() {
    $('#conversion').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (!$('#iframe').length) {
        $('#pixelframe').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="' + pd + '" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = lk;
        }, 5000);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```